# how I can create community sub site under publishing site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a publishing site collection, I need to create a new community sub site under this site collection. how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll first need to go into Site Settings and set "Community Site" as an allowed subsite template.

**Site settings** > **Page layout and site template settings** > **Subsite templates**

Move "Community site" across the right, then scroll down and hit ok. You'll also need to activate the Site Collection feature "SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features" - this makes the community site available to create a subsite with.

Next, visit "Site content" and click "new subsite". You can now create a Community Site from the "Collaboration" tab.

As a side note, you should select "use unique permissions" for the community site, which ensures everyone has the right access levels.